# Finding the inverse of a function with multiple x terms.

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be the function y→ (1−y^3)/y
on (0,∞).
Deduce that f has an inverse g : R → (0, ∞) which is continuous.

I've got to y=1/(y^2+x) but always end with a y term in the answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that the problem does not ask you to find the inverse.

Comment: Is there some reason that you’ve deleted the original text of your question? Doing so after you’ve received and accepted an answer is bad form and could be taken as a sign that you’re cheating on your homework/exam and are trying to cover your tracks.

Comment: I realised after that I misread the question and didnt think the question was needed. @amd. Sorry if this is frowned upon

Comment: If you want to withdraw a question, delete the entire thing instead of editing the text away. Now as it stands, there’s an answer that has no relation whatsoever to the current text of your question.

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to. I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Your function is rational, and hence continuous on the domain. If the function is a continuous monotonous function, then it is a bijection, then it has an inverse, and this inverse has to be continuous as well.